# css transition unexpectedly affecting multiple different properties

Tags: html, css

I'm am currently learning CSS and need help understanding how the transition function affects different properties. When I try to add a transition function to one property of a button it seems to affect multiple different properties.

```
.join-button{
    background-color: white;
    color : rgb(79, 139, 228);
    border-color:rgb(16, 46, 92); 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 62px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: color, 10s;
  }

  .join-button:hover{ 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color:rgb(228, 79, 109);
    height: 100px;
  }
```

I expected only the color to change over a period of 10 seconds when I hovered on the button, In reality all the properties inside hover changed over a time of 10 seconds. I want to know how to only target the color.

Comment: Remove the comma from your transition statement. Should be `transition: color 10s;`

Comment: @HunterTurner that worked, than you